# Can't assign to operator

Tags: python, python-2.7, variable-assignment

```
i = 0
num = 0
while i <= 1000:
    if i % 3 and i % 5 == 0:
        num + i = num <--- Adding Up Numbers Divisable by 3 & 5...
    i += 1
print num
```

Error:*** can't assign to operator (line 5)

Comment: `num + i` returns a value... how would assign a value to a value? It's like writing `6 = 5`.

Comment: Why the downvote? OP clearly has a fundamental misunderstanding of how assignments work, has posted the code and error message, why not just help? (I've seen many people new to programming stumble over this)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you sure you don't want:

```
num = num + i
```

or equivalently:

```
num += i
```

?

Note that this can be done  a little easier using `sum`, `range` and a generator expression:

```
sum( x for x in range(0,1000,5) if x % 3 == 0 )
                            #^only take every 5th element (0, 5, 10, 15 ...)
                                    #^ Also only take elements divisible by 3
```

If you're planning on running this code on only python 2.x, you can change `range` to `xrange` in the above expression.  Also, when reading other people's code, you'll sometimes see `if x % 3 == 0` written as `if not x % 3` in this type of context, but I prefer the first version (it seems a little more explicit to me).

Comment: I'd rather use `xrange(0, 1000, 5)` and test for `x % 3 == 0`. It would run in less iterations.

Comment: @IhorKaharlichenko -- Sure, `xrange` is better for python2.x (which the OP is using).  However, the future is python 3.x, so I like to write my code to work with both whenever possible.  For something like this, the differences between `xrange` and `range` are probably negligible.

Comment: Well, yes, for the sake of py3k portability `range()` is better than `xrange()`. Though swapping 3 with 5 would have an impact.

Comment: @IhorKaharlichenko -- You're right.  I just noticed the `xrange` in your first comment and not the actual important part :).  Thanks for the input.

Comment: @Levon -- Thanks.  It's always nice when someone who consistently writes quality posts gives positive feedback :-)

Comment: @mgilson Right back at you :) sometimes I think the tone of the post is as important than the contents. Some experienced people sometimes seem to forget that not everyone is at their level.

Answer (score 2):

```
num + i = num <--- Adding Up Numbers Divisable by 3 & 5...
```

You cannot assign a value to an expression.

Also, why not just add 5 each time and check that it is divisible by 3? You'll already know it is divisible by 5...